# "Complete" indication that doesn't insinuate "correct"?

Tags: user-expectation, confirmation, plugins

I have something like a multistep wizard plugin, except that you can freely switch between any step in the wizard, once a selection is made from the bottom choices an overlay appears to signify a choice has been made, proceed to the next step.

Right now my overlay is this (it is a somewhat transparent overlay):
[image]

However, I feel like this gives the idea of making the "correct" or "right" choice. If one of the steps in this wizard is say a Terms of Service (just an example) and the user hits decline, this may be confusing as typically declining the terms of service is the "bad/wrong" choice.

Now remember I am doing this from the developer/plugin creator point of view, so I can't create a custom overlay per scenario because this wizard could be used for any number of reasons. I could create a small subset of overlays (positive, negative, neutral) and let whoever uses the plugin pick which the response to trigger, but this seems like a case of over customization.

Is there a context neutral response that (stylishly) says "you made a choice" without implying a positive or negative response?

Answer (score 2):

From your sample and context it does not make sense. If your intent is to show the progress then it must be progressive. Canceling one of the steps would only mean breaking that path. However if the intent is complete a step regardless of order that will work. To put things into perspective, I provided two samples one that would make sense and the other does not.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I didn't make one thing clear I apologize and will edit, but you can switch freely between steps of the wizard. So just because it appears first doesn't mean it needs to be answered first. Also, the ToS was just a random example, it could also be something like "would you like to add this additional product" and you hit decline, but you still need to answer the rest of the wizard.